# What's the equation on this postcard from Norbert Wiener's archive?

Tags: calculus

Can anyone explain to me, a philosopher who is completely ignorant in maths---so in everyday language please---, if the equation on this postcard means anything at all, and if so what? The postcard is from the archive of Norbert Wiener and was printed in Austria. I think it's from the 1910s but could be wrong. If the answer is relevant to what I'm writing I will gladly thank you in the book I am writing.

Also I'm assuming the mathematician is just a generic caricature and not meant to represent anyone in particular, but if you think otherwise please add this to your answer. You may perhaps agree that the mathematician bears a striking resemblance to the mature Wiener himself!

[Postcard of a Mathematiker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGkNT.jpg)

Edit: Updated question to not assume that the equation carries significance.

Comment: Since the left hand side of the equation is not shown, probably nothing. It reads like a routine algebraic expression which could appear halfway through some calculation

Comment: Where did you find my picture ?

Comment: I think it is not the question *this site* concerns.

Comment: It *might* be a reasonable question for [history of science and math](https://hsm.stackexchange.com), but here's an important thing to keep in mind: there is a long tradition of cartoon depictions of scientists and mathematicians writing mathematical nonsense on blackboards; this looks like one of those.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I assumed that mathematics also concerned its own own history, but perhaps here I am approaching things too much from my own disciplinary assumptions.